# Unable to create a copy of a table when passing its name via %s

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create temporary copies of tables with parametrized names for my calculations, but somehow I can't create the tables using %s way.

This issue is very confusing. I have tens of select\insert\update queries using same formatting, but it seems to be not working with `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...`

My code:

```
query_order = "SELECT Order_ID FROM Reels_In_Order WHERE Reel_Manufacturer_ID = %s"

query_create_copy_order_table = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s'

con = mdb.connect(user=self.user, password=self.pswd, database=self.db)

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute(query_order, (GUI_entry_string,))
order_id = cur.fetchall()

copy_table_name = "Copy_Order_"+order_id[0][0]
print(copy_table_name)

query_copy_order_to_enter = (copy_table_name,)

cur.execute(query_create_copy_order_table, query_copy_order_to_enter)
```

And it throws an error

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Copy_Order_2'' at line 1
```

or this, using `CREATE LIKE` method

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Copy_Order_2' LIKE Reels_In_Order' at line 1
```

I'm out of ideas. Tried changing this ugly `"Copy_Order_"+order_id[0][0]` with plain `"Copy_Order_2"` and got the same errors. Tuple is being properly created and passed into the query like in my other select\update queries. Also tried closing and opening connection again, but this isnt the case, same errors.

Comment: Table name CANNOT be a parameter, because it is parsed literally. Use prepared statement, stored procedure, or substitute the placeholder with the value on PHP side.

Comment: @akina but why... Gotta implement procedures then, thanks.